# How to copy the content of particular location in matrix when it is in for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is the below code in matlab. I am trying to copy the contents of the matrix location a{2,3}(2 row ,3 column) if there exists else I want to copy the contents of the location a{1,3} (1st row, 3rd column).But it is checking only for a{2,3} when it comes to a{1,3} it is throwing the error

```
data759c = [1 1 1 1 1]' and final = [1 1 1 0 1]' for 2X3
                                    [1 1 1 1 1]' for 1X3

for i = 1:size(final,2)
s1 = (data759c(:,1)== final(:,i));
a = tabulate(s1);
if (size(a) == a{1,3})
  b(i) = a{1,3}(1);
else 
b(i) = a{2,3}(1);  
end
end

a will be either 

1  4  80
0  1  20

0r 

1  5  100 

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in wmojvot (line 22)
b(i) = a{2,3}(1);
```

can any one help why I am getting the error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What does `if size(a) == a{1,3}` imply?

Comment: @rayryeng I am checking the size of matrix if it is 1X3 then I want to copy the 3rd location of that matrix else the other

Comment: Then you will want `if all(size(a) == size(a{1,3}))`... though I really don't understand why you are doing it this way.

Comment: @rayryeng I want to check condition for both. For each iteration in the loop, 'a' will be either 2X3 or 1X3 if it is 1X3 i will copy the content of 3rd location else  a is 2X3 it will copy the content of 2nd row 3rd location.

Comment: @rayryeng above condition you mentioned is not working

Comment: Again... please provide a [mcve]